# Cyanogenmod - Filesystem for 64GB SD card, files larger than 4GB

Tags: cyanogenmod, external-sd, ntfs

Every time I find a thread on the Internet describing "how to get your 64GB SD card to work with Cyanogenmod", the answer is always the same: format it to FAT32.

FAT32 does not support files larger than 4GB. Does Cyanogenmod (10.1) support a decent file system that can take files larger than that?

Comment: Do you need it to work with Windows?

Comment: No. If you are going to mention EXT4, there seem to be lots of issues with permissions with that, but go ahead if you have a solution.

Answer (score 5):

On yesterday's CyanogenMod nightly, I performed the following steps:

1. Unmount the SD card in the UI
2. Erase the SD card in the UI (this recreates the partition table itself and creates a new FAT32 fs)
3. Unmount the SD card again, if needed
4. Plug in the phone
5. Open a shell with adb shell
6. su to root (this has to be enabled in Settings)
7. Run `make_ext4fs /dev/block/mmcblk1p1` to create the new ext4 fs
8. Mount the SD card in the UI (you'll have to unplug the phone to do this)
9. Reopen the root shell and run `chown media_rw:media_rw /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1` to give the folder the expected owner
10. Run `chmod 775 /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1` to make the sdcard writable

Having done this, the card is mounted automatically by CyanogenMod, and it can be written to from file managers without root privileges. I also copied music and pictures to the filesystem, and after a reboot, they are indexed and shown in Apollo and Gallery. I've only been using it for less than a day, but it's been working like a better FAT32 fs so far.

Comment: Do other apps work well? For instance, is poweramp able to find the music?

Comment: I'm using CM11 (11-20140804-SNAPSHOT-M9), and your step 8 does not work for me. It says "checking for errors", but then it ends without saying anything nor mounting. However, if I ssh to android, I'm able to mount with `mount -t ext4 -o rw,noatime /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1`

Comment: @David I use Apollo, and it's able to find music. I do have an issue where if I unmount and remount the SD card, then all of my playlists are invalidated; I'm not sure if that's related to the filesystem or not.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit that's a good tip. I don't remember what behaviour I was seeing if I tried to mount while plugging in, but it may have been similar.

Answer (score 2):

The "proper" answer would be exFAT. "Proper" because exFAT is crap but since it does "fix" some of FAT's problems, it is the only hassle-free option.

Forget NTFS.

Ext4 would be a much better option. Should it be properly managed in Android regarding rights management - from my quite recent understanding (latest CM11 as of Jan 2015), Android does not expect the true external storage to understarnd, let alone enfore access rights. Since *FAT has no concept of any rights, this is no problem. However, in Linux there is no clean way of disabling rights management on a native filesystem. Android's concept of security uses UNIX access rights in a different way than it was intended. Not to blame Android, the UNIX concept is ancient but it's use comes at a price. The price being the need of external rights management which Android is not ready for and the User has (usually) no control of either.

There is a way to use ext4 on Android, called Mounts2SD. It's quite clean and reliable though it is anything but native (made of "nasty hacks" some would say). I wouldn't recommend it unless you have absolute confidence in what you are doing.