# How can I mount an ext4-formatted SD card with correct permissions (with root)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, external-sd, root-access, ext4

I see some mentions here of creating an ext4-formatted SD card, but no guide. [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11301/sd-card-formatted-to-ext4-and-permissions) closely-related question suggests there is no way to do it, but my question differs in that my phone is specifically rooted.

I formatted my card as ext4 (GUID partition-table); my Cyanogenmod phone mounted it at `/mnt/fuse/sdcard1`. I followed instructions [here](https://blog.jplitza.de/2013/07/04/external-sd-card-with-ext4-under-android-cm10-1/) to mount the card at `/storage/sdcard1`, by creating the following script at `/data/local/userinit.sh`

```
#!/system/bin/sh
REALMNT=/mnt/fuse/sdcard1_real
if ! [ -d "$REALMNT" ]; then
  mkdir "$REALMNT" || exit 1
fi
mount -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 "$REALMNT"
sdcard "$REALMNT" /storage/sdcard1 1023 1023 &
```

I restarted and attempting to copy a file (using ES File Explorer) and paste it into its parent directory, which failed:

```
/storage/sdcard1/foo/bar.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied).
```

I can actually play the file fine, so I *can* open it. FWIW, when I try copying from the original mount point (`/mnt/fuse/sdcard1`), I get a slightly different error:

```
Failed to copy the file bar.mp3
```

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Cyanogenmod 10.2.0-i9300.

==EDIT==

```
su
ls -l /mnt/fuse
drwxrwxr-x media_rw media_rw   2014-03-04 22:08 sdcard1
```

That was all. There is no `sdcard1_real` in this directory, so I suppose the script is failing?

==EDIT2==

I tried modifying the script to troubleshoot. The script begins fine, but then fails on `mkdir "$REALMNT"` with the error `/data/local/userinit.sh[6]: : not found`.

==EDIT3==

I know that the script doesn't work, so fixing it might solve my question, but I thought the following was interesting. I formatted my SD card in my Linux computer, and transferred some files to it. Oddly enough, permission errors only occur in the subdirectories that I created. In the root of the partition (via `/storage/sdcard1`), I already have write permission.

Comment: As root, please execute `ls -l /mnt/fuse/` and `ls -l /mnt/fuse/sdcard1_real`. Then [edit] your question to include the results. My *guess* is "wrong file permissions" – either for the mount, or for the `foo/` directory on the card. Remember, ext4 supports full *nix file permissions, incl. user and groups.

Comment: You type `su` in terminal to get root.  You may need to confirm granting the permission on the phone, if you're doing it for the first time.

Comment: Either the script is failing, or it's not executed at all. You might wish to add some debug output, e.g. `echo Script executed > /mnt/fuse/sdcard1/test.log`, and check if it is running at all. If so, make the previous-to-last line `mount -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 "$REALMNT" 2> /mnt/fuse/sdcard1/test.log` and check the error message. Or execute the script manually to see: `su /data/local/userinit.sh`.

Comment: @Izzy `touch` shows that the script is running. I tried executing the script manually with `su /data/local/userinit.sh`, but this failed. I also tried `su echo foo`, and get a similar error: `Unknown id: echo`.

Comment: As for your EDIT3, see my first comment: *ext4 supports full *nix file permissions, incl. user and groups*. You've created those directories with a user that doesn't exist on your Android device, so they belong to "unknown user / unknown group". If you didn't grant write access to "world", only root could write there. You should make yourself familiar with those *nix basics when using such a file system on portable media ;) As for the script, I again suggest adding some more debug information, e.g. using `echo` to output each command before it's executed, and redirect error output with `2>>`.

Comment: @Izzy If I understand correctly, the purpose of the script is to fix these permission inconsistencies? I _did_ do more debugging, but perhaps EDIT2 wasn't clear enough. The script ran up to `exit 1`, then failed with the error stated.

Comment: Could it be the script runs too early, and `/mnt/fuse` is not there when you try to `mkdir` (try putting an `ls /mnt` before the `mount` command)? If so, a `mkdir -p "$REALMNT" || exit 1` could work around that – but I'm not sure to the side-effects when the system tries to create `/mnt/fuse` later and it does already exist.

Comment: Related: [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526)

Comment: @IrfanLatif I don't have a phone with an SD card anymore, but unlike your answer in the link, I don't remember any problems with "every app will create files with its own UID", as per my answer below. I can't really check this anymore unfortunately though. Anyway hopefully your link is useful to some here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was [supposedly](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/68714/32143) fixed several months ago, but people are still reporting problems. I can read items on the card, but do not have write permission. To fix it, I combined strategies from a [few](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58233/cyanogenmod-filesystem-for-64gb-sd-card-files-larger-than-4gb/75306#75306) [sources](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/79157-ext4-for-storagesdcard1/page__st__20).

1. Partition card with MS-DOS partition table and ext4 filesystem. I used GParted on my (Linux) desktop computer.
2. Insert the card into your phone. (You will probably not have write access now.)
3. Open the [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en), installed by default in Cyanogenmod.
4. Type in the following (I recommend [WiFi Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.volosyukivan&hl=en) for large blocks of text). Give the emulator root privileges when it requests them.

The `$` and `#` indicate prompts, so don't type them in.

```
$ su
# chown media_rw:media_rw /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1
# chmod g+w /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1
```

This changes the SD card's permissions. The owner and group change from `system` to `media_rw`, and it also gives the group write access.

Comment: need -R for recursif 
          chown -R media_rw:media_rw /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is any help, but possibly the issue is that that you are trying to mount in the wrong place ? This is my working script that works on an S3 mini with CM11:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
REALMNT=/mnt/media_rw/sdcard1
if ! [ -d "$REALMNT" ]; then
mkdir "$REALMNT" || exit 1
fi
mount -t ext4 -o rw,noatime /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 "$REALMNT"
sdcard "$REALMNT" /storage/sdcard1 1023 1023
```

The REALMNT location already existed, so of course the mkdir was never called.
And media_rw/sdcard1 is already owned by media_rw

I also had to update /etc/permissions/platform.xml to include:
`<group id="media_rw"/>` 
in:
`<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">`

Comment: Thanks. I'd somewhat given up on this, since I also had high battery usage with my script. Since it's fixed in trunk, I won't bother with a workaround any more. Thanks though, and +1.

Comment: @Sparhawk: Not sure which CYM version you use, but my SD card is not mounted automatically.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit I'm not sure if you meant to reply to [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/68714/32143). Anyway, I'm using 11-20140804-SNAPSHOT-M9-i9300. I've posted more info in [another answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/82518/32143).

Comment: @Sparhawk: My card is not even mounted, and the mount procedure in Settings fails. Maybe the problme is related my question here (`su` fails to mount`): `http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82089/difference-between-su-vs-root-ssh-login-for-mounting` I use cm-11-20140804-SNAPSHOT-M9-mondrianwifi.zip .

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Not really sure. Perhaps ask a new question?

Comment: @Sparhawk: I've asked several questions about CYM, and got not a single answer. Without even using CYM much I've faced several bugs (like this one), and noone has been able to give a clue about any of them (not in stackexchange, nor in CYM forum). I think I'll install another custom ROM, a more solid one. This is simply not working properly for me.

Comment: I used this script in Stock Android 4.4.4 (Galaxy Note 4), but the files in /storage/sdcard1/ are shown with ownership 0.1015 instead of 1023.1023, giving lots of 'permission denied' errors of course. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer posted up by [adasdadasd](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/59892/adasdadasd) that I wanted to accept, but has since been deleted. I'll reproduce it below, and accept my answer, but if adasdadasd resurfaces, please repost and I'll delete this and accept yours.

> https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-332
>
> https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_providers_MediaProvider/commit/faf3f77b9222554227740aed8127714ea9e3f407
>
> Fixed by default? New change in github.

Answer (score 0):

Here the simpeline

```
#!/system/bin/sh
REALMNT="/mnt/media_rw/extSdCard"
mount -t ext4 -o rw,noatime /dev/block/mmcblk1p1     "$REALMNT"
sdcard "$REALMNT" /storage/extSdCard 1023 1023 &
```

And here writable ext4 on external sd

```
#!/system/bin/sh
chown media_rw:media_rw /mnt/media_rw/extSdCard
chmod g+w /mnt/media_rw/extSdCard
```

You can change "extSdCard" like "sdcard1" where your external sdcard mounted

Iam used stockrom with Kingroot, but I try Supersu its trouble with mounting filesystem