# Difference between su vs root SSH login for mounting?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting

I have a bash script `luks` that I use in Android for mounting/umounting encrypted devices, that can be called in a terminal emulator with

```
 su -c "luks ..."
```

The script works ok for the first part, except at the mounting time, that in the script I do with:

```
 busybox mount /dev/mapper/${vol_arg} ${mount_path}
```

Despite the fact that I get exitcode 0 from this command, the device is not mounted. The command line

```
 su -c "mount /dev/mapper/${vol_arg} ${mount_path}"
```

does not work either in the terminal emulator yet it shows no error (`df` does not shows the device). When I try to execute it agan, I get `mounting failed: device or resource busy`. If I then try

```
 su -c "umount ${mount_path}"
```

I also get `cant't umount...: device or resource busy`. What's happening?

However, the REALLY strange point here is that, if I `SSH` to the tablet as root with the same terminal emulator, the command

```
 mount /dev/mapper/${vol_arg} ${mount_path}
```

mounts the device normally (??!!). In addition, if I execute the command

```
 'luks ...'
```

as SSHd root, it also works perfectly, even mounting the device.

Why does mounting is working if run as SSH root, and not through `su -c`?

Even more strange is the fact that the `su -c` thing works fine in Samsung Android 4.1.2, but not in Cyanogenmod 11 (4.4.2)...

Maybe the cyanogenmod people introduced some ugly bug?

Clues?

Thanks!!

L.

Comment: Now this is funny: after mounting through SSH, the root user sees the content of the volume in the `${mount_path}`, as desired, while other users/apps see the previous content of the `${mount_path}`!! It seems that Cyanogenmod mounting routines are broken.

Comment: Not a single answer...?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to CYM 11 M10, and now su works fine. No doubt it was a bug. So now I can mount/umount encrypted stuff as I was always able to do.

It seems the problem is solved in the M10 build.